# Educational Games

Tags: discussion, scope, games

Can we put educational games as an answer for question like this?

- [Android application to learn English for small kids](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26/android-application-to-learn-english-for-small-kids)

Maybe should I make this clear in my question, that I'm not asking for games for kids, because without this users can close my questions as offtopic?

Comment: I'd say that **1:** as long as the question itself isn't asking for games, the question itself is on topic and **2:** even if the answer is a game, as long as it fits the needs of the question, it's a good answer.

Comment: So, *Android games to learn English for small kids* is bad for this site?

Answer (score 3):

I think that's fine.

[I'm against having game recommendations here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic/53#53), but educational games are a different breed. There is a fine line between educational games and educational software that isn't really a game. The focus of educational software is a concrete, objective goal: to learn something. That's very different from the usual focus of games which is to have fun.

A question that asks (with sufficient detail) “how can I learn something?” is in the same mold as, say, [Brain trainer — exercise perception, cognition and memory](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/328/brain-trainer-exercise-perception-cognition-and-memory). Some of the answers may be games, but the purpose is using the software (which may happen to be a game) for learning. That's as valid a purpose as any.

Comment: +1. To those who think "game!=useful", StackExchange itself can be officially thought of as a game (as per its design that is heavy on gamification :)

Comment: Duolingo teaches language, Quake teaches reflex etc :)