# Would plugin recommendations about Minecraft be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, games

So for example "Plugin for Bukkit that will rollback changes on a Minecraft server" or "Plugin for Bukkit that will

So long as the question is specific in what plugin the user is looking for, I don't see a problem, other than the fact that it is asking about a game.

I was reading [this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic) meta question but I wasn't sure what the line was between asking for recommendations *for* a game, and asking for recommendations *about* a game.

Comment: Yeah, we support browser plugins, so I don't see how it would be an issue.

Comment: Great question. We do need to figure this out, and I'm not sure as to what the answer is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is already in the linked question:

> What editor for [GAME]” is a software recommendation that happens to be related to playing games — again, **that's for-a-purpose software, so it's fine.**

and

> A question asking what OS is most fun to debug would not be. Conversely, **a question asking about Minecraft or Kerbal Space Program mods for worldbuilding would be on-topic**. The distinction is not the primary purpose of the software, but the primary purpose of the recommendation.

(emphasis mine)

If I'm not incorrect, I believe that a plugin is even farther away from a mod for a game - and thus it should be on-topic.

Comment: Oh I must have missed that.

Comment: I agree with this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Whether or to what extent games are on-topic are still being debated. However this case appears to be uncontroversially on-topic. From [my answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic/53#53), which is rather towards the anti-game side of the spectrum:

> “What editor for [GAME]” is a software recommendation that happens to be related to playing games — again, that's for-a-purpose software, so it's fine.

As long as the purpose of the software is to accomplish a concrete task (as opposed to being entertained), it's irrelevant that the concrete task happens to be related to a game.

Comment: I don't consider this the same as other game recommendations. He isn't asking for a game, but a plugin, and that is a lot more specific.

Comment: @Seth Yes, which is why I say it's uncontroversially on-topic.