# Is asking for Drupal modules and/or themes on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Asking recommendations to find an appropriate contributed [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) module or theme is not considered as [on topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/). Do we count the contributed Drupal modules and/or theme as softwares also?

I see that asking for [plugins for Minecraft](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/6389) is acceptable, as well as asking for [plugins for Wordpress](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2328). So I don't think contributed modules and/or themes for Drupal should be an exception. Any idea?

**Note**: For reference, currently we have [10 questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tagged with ***Drupal***, quite a few of them ask for contributed modules or themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say your question here already contains the answer – as long as your question there is specific enough (i.e. follows the general rules), I don't see why Drupal *modules* should be dealt with differently than Wordpress plugins.

Themes might be a different topic, though, as they don't have a "practical component" (other than "looking nice"), and thus rather fall into the category "resources" (like icons and images); so these IMHO would be off-topic.

Comment: OK "maestro", thanks for this interesting answer! Please consider my question (and my related answer) that I just posted (at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28498) as an example  of such questions. Any feedback about its content (in the context of this question/answer here) would be greatly appreciated. **Note** (about themes): what's your answer here in the context of the question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17245 (consider expanding your answer on that maybe ...)?

Comment: I prefer leaving *that* part to someone more familiar with it :) Reading the question, it seems like Drupal themes do more than "theme-ing" – but I cannot tell whether OP has based that on wrong assumptions, or whatever. I myself do not use 3rd party CMS.

Comment: Indeed, drupal themes do waaaaay more than "theme-ing". Even though it's consider as a bad "practise", you can include all sorts of "logic" (written in PHP) in such themes. So therefor I think for "themes" questions that "might" fit could be like "What's your recommended base-theme to build a responsive website in Drupal?" (note: "base"-theme is another Drupalisme ...).

Comment: Thanks for the details, Pierre! I still prefer someone else covers this part – as it's really outside my expertise. It might even be wise to have that a separate question – but a separate answer might do as well. I'd suggest, until such an answer is posted, ***everyone in favor of Drupal themes being on-topic as in the previous comment, upvoting that comment.*** That way we at least have an indicator :)

Comment: OK, good enough as a compromise for now ... You know I can't "upvote" my own comment, right? But do count me in please. If "Drupal themes" questions are OK, then maybe it may make sense to have extra tags "drupal-modules" and "drupal-themes" created. Whereas the existing "drupal"-tag is used for any type of drupal questions that are not specific to modules or themes ... eg: "Should I use Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 these days when starting a new Drupal site?" ... Now woudn't **that** be an interesting "software recommendation" question?

Comment: Sorry, Pierre: "Should I use Drupal 7 or Drupal 8" would be off-topic (see e.g. [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)), as is "how do I X with Z". So the `drupal` tag would be for modules or themes anyway :) // And sure, you can't upvote your own comment. You were *asking* that – and *others* should place the Yay or Nay. ;)

Comment: OK, I understand, and agree ... merci!

Comment: @Izzy: it was not clear to me which comment to upvote, so I added another answer for themes.

Answer (score 3):

**Themes should be on-topic as well**

- Themes are not a web service. They can be installed locally (on a webserver)
- Themes provide more than just a nice look. E.g. Wordpress themes can or cannot provide a menu, which may be an essential feature.
- While a theme typically comes with pictures and icons (which are off-topic), you normally want to exchange them, while you keep the layout and the features of the theme