# Testing the game recommendation category of questions

Tags: discussion, scope, games

**Related**: [Are video game related questions on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic)

Below are a variety of game recommendation questions that we saw on the gaming Stack Exchange, Arqade, during its life. I have split these into separate answers, categorised by what is wrong with them in the hope that we can use the information in this post to build our own policy on game recommendations.

All of these questions were raised by users of Arqade. Some of these users dropped by just to ask this question and some of these users went on to become established users, so the quality levels of the posts varies quite wildly.

**The purpose of this post is so that we as a site can rapidly analyse a large number of questions that the internet in general would deem as "game recommendation" questions, so we can either fine tune our policy on what is acceptable or determine that game recommendation questions are in fact off topic.**

Comment: For anyone voting on the answers: reread the purpose, and vote whether they are **good examples** of the mentioned type or not. Do not vote whether they are **good questions**.

Comment: If you decide to edit your examples in the answers after more feedback (e.g. I think some examples in *Super low quality/ambiguous posts* should not be in that answer), please do not remove any examples but strike through them - otherwise our comments become nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

## These questions are specific

In fact, with the right presentation, I'd possibly suggest that if we allowed game recommendations, some of these might even be borderline acceptable.

- They provide a list of requirements
- They give examples of what suggestions would be acceptable
- They narrow the scope down on genre, platform, etc

I'm not saying they're flawless, but these aren't that far off some of the questions [we already have on the site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## These aren't even asking about a game

These game recommendation questions ask for resources on guides to assist in finding new games. These are website/resource recommendations and are squarely outside of the scope of this site. If they were asked here - I would vote to close them as off topic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second example could be improved to meet [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) but right now it indeed is not good enough.

Answer (score -1):

## Super low quality/ambiguous posts

These questions fail to meet our quality requirements as discussed here: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

These questions are either really short with no specified requirements, or far too broad in a way that would result in answers that would generally not be useful for future visitors. These questions often focus on a single specific feature with no attempt to narrow down the platform, genre, or any other requirement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In would reject the first one as too broad, the content of second one looks OK but it could become too long a list, and the third one I would accept. Maybe they just need some additional info such as price, OS. So I'm downvoting this answer as not being good examples of *Super low quality/amiguous*